How to write down a bash script to **Completely Uninstall OpenPanel** from My Ubuntu Server?
I encountered a critical system error while using OpenPanel on my Ubuntu server. After some investigation, I discovered that the current version of OpenPanel (v0.2.7) is still in the process of troubleshooting HTTPS protocol, DNS allocation, and certificate management.
The issue arose when I attempted to use these beta features. After installation, the OpenPanel website went down, and I couldn’t bring it back up using the command:
opencli admin on

I have been struggling to uninstall OpenPanel from my system. Unfortunately, the support team was not able to provide a clear solution. They mentioned that I need to manually reverse the steps in the installation bash script, which seems impractical and error-prone. (Super sad but during my troubleshooting efforts, I also faced a Docker crash error, which has further complicated the situation.)
Does anyone have a reliable method to completely uninstall OpenPanel from an Ubuntu server?
I tried below method, but didn't work.
nano fix.sh && bash fix.sh

Then pasted this content:
#!/bin/bash

service admin stop
rm -rf /usr/local/admin/.git

rm -rf /usr/local/admin/*

current_python_version=$(python3 --version 2>&1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1,2 | tr -d '.')
OPENPADMIN_DIR="/usr/local/admin/" #openadmin files


    if [ -f /etc/os-release ] && grep -q "Ubuntu 22" /etc/os-release; then   
        echo "Downloading files for Ubuntu22 and python version $current_python_version"
        git clone -b $current_python_version --single-branch https://github.com/stefanpejcic/openadmin $OPENPADMIN_DIR
        cd $OPENPADMIN_DIR
         pip install --default-timeout=3600 -r requirements.txt
    # Ubuntu 24
    elif [ -f /etc/os-release ] && grep -q "Ubuntu 24" /etc/os-release; then
        echo "Downloading files for Ubuntu24 and python version $current_python_version"
        git clone -b $current_python_version --single-branch https://github.com/stefanpejcic/openadmin $OPENPADMIN_DIR
        cd $OPENPADMIN_DIR
         pip install --default-timeout=3600 -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages

        # on ubuntu24 we need to use overlay instead of devicemapper!
        OVERLAY=true
        
    # Debian12 and 11
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
        echo "Installing PIP and Git"
        apt-get install git pip python3-yaml -y > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "Downloading files for Debian and python version $current_python_version"
        git clone -b debian-$current_python_version --single-branch https://github.com/stefanpejcic/openadmin $OPENPADMIN_DIR
        cd $OPENPADMIN_DIR
         pip install --default-timeout=3600 -r requirements.txt
         pip install --default-timeout=3600 -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages
    # other
    fi



service admin start

PANEL_VERSION="0.2.3"

    mkdir -p /usr/local/admin

    wget -O /tmp/opencli.tar.gz "https://storage.googleapis.com/openpanel/${PANEL_VERSION}/get.openpanel.co/downloads/${PANEL_VERSION}/opencli/opencli-main.tar.gz" > /dev/null 2>&1

    mkdir -p /tmp/opencli

    cd /tmp/ && tar -xzf opencli.tar.gz -C /tmp/opencli
    mkdir -p /usr/local/admin/scripts
    cp -r /tmp/opencli/* /usr/local/admin/scripts > /dev/null 2>&1 || cp -r /tmp/opencli/opencli-main /usr/local/admin/scripts > /dev/null 2>&1 

    rm /tmp/opencli.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1
    rm -rf /tmp/opencli > /dev/null 2>&1

    cp  /usr/local/admin/scripts/opencli /usr/local/bin/opencli
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/opencli > /dev/null 2>&1
    chmod +x -R /usr/local/admin/scripts/ > /dev/null 2>&1
    opencli commands
    
    source ~/.bashrc



docker stop openpanel
docker rm openpanel

docker pull openpanel/openpanel

cd /root
docker compose down && docker compose up -d


To address this, I created an uninstall script that effectively removes OpenPanel and its components from my Ubuntu server. Here’s the script I used:
#!/bin/bash

echo "Uninstalling OpenPanel..."

sudo -i

cd /root && docker compose down
docker rmi -f mysql/mysql-server openpanel/openpanel nginx:alpine certbot/certbot:latest ubuntu/bind9:latest openpanel/nginx openpanel/apache 

rm ~/docker-compose.yml
rm ~/initialize.sql

echo "Removing cron job..."
if [ -f /etc/cron.d/openpanel ]; then
    rm /etc/cron.d/openpanel
else
    echo "No cron job found for OpenPanel."
fi

echo "Removing OpenPanel directory..."
rm -r /usr/local/panel

echo "Stopping and disabling admin service..."
systemctl stop admin
systemctl disable admin
rm /etc/systemd/system/admin.service
rm -r /usr/local/admin

echo "Removing OpenCLI..."
rm /usr/local/bin/opencli
sed -i '/# opencli aliases/,+3d' ~/.bashrc
hash -d opencli || echo "No opencli command found."

echo "Removing OpenPanel configuration..."
rm -r /etc/openpanel

echo "Uninstallation complete."

After running this script, I was able to completely remove OpenPanel from my system. If anyone else is facing similar issues, I hope this script helps you uninstall OpenPanel effectively.
Troubleshooting Tips

If you encounter any errors or if certain commands fail, try running
the script with sudo privileges and making the script executable with
chmod +x uninstall.sh.

Ensure that you are running the script from the correct directory
or provide the full path to the docker-compose.yml file.

If you still face issues with Docker, try restarting the Docker
service or checking its logs for more information.



https://medium.com/@tilak559/complete-guide-to-installing-and-uninstalling-docker-on-ubuntu-c7cace26ede7


Update from OpenPanel Community Administrator:
techguru0, I appreciate the time you took into creating this and that you decided to share it, thank you!
I would also just add removing all logs:
rm -rf /var/log/openpanel

and the install log from /root.
And a few leftover services:
# Floating IP

service floatingip stop 
systemctl disable floatingip
rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/floatingip.service 

# Logrotate

rm -rf /etc/logrotate.d/openpanel
rm -rf /etc/logrotate.d/syslog

systemctl daemon-reload

Also, UFW/CSF is added by OpenPanel and these:
packages=("docker.io" "default-mysql-client" "python3-pip" "pip" "gunicorn" "jc" "sqlite3" "geoip-bin" "xfsprogs")


By following these steps, you can ensure a cleaner uninstallation process and avoid potential issues with leftover configurations. Thanks to Stefan for sharing this valuable information!

After struggling with the beta functionality of OpenPanel, I realized that this project is indeed a game changer for web hosting management. OpenPanel offers a powerful and flexible solution for Linux systems, providing users with a VPS-like experience at a fraction of the cost.
OpenPanel github link
Live platform
